Audio File Won't Download Properly From Huggingface Streaming Dataset
I'm running this code to stream the huggingface dataset mozilla-foundation/common_voice_17_0:
language = "en"
buffer_size = 100
streaming_dataset = load_dataset("mozilla-foundation/common_voice_17_0", language, split="train",
                                 use_auth_token=True, trust_remote_code=True, streaming=True)


dataset = streaming_dataset.shuffle(
    seed=1137, buffer_size=buffer_size
)
common_voice = buffer_dataset(dataset, buffer_size)

sample = random.choice(common_voice)

audio_file = sample["path"]

Everything is fine until I try to load the audio file from the streaming dataset in this line:
waveform, sample_rate = torchaudio.load(audio_file)

Then I get this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  "... .venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/soundfile.py", line 1216, in _open
    raise LibsndfileError(err, prefix="Error opening {0!r}: ".format(self.name))
soundfile.LibsndfileError: Error opening 'en_train_14/common_voice_en_18837621.mp3': System error.


I've tried loading the dataset without streaming using a smaller split than 'en' and that worked fine, but this is not a feasible solution for large splits like 'en'.
I was trying to mess around with maybe downloading the file via the huggingface API, but I wasn't sure how to do that or if that is possible.
The problem appears to be that the audio file is not downloading when I set 'streaming=True'.
If anyone could suggest solutions or just a way to download the audio file separately using info gathered from the streaming huggingface object I would greatly appreciate it!

You can download the file locally before trying to load it with torchaudio. Hugging Face's datasets library provides a way to download files manually. Here’s how you can do it:
from datasets import load_dataset
import torchaudio
import requests
import os

# Load the streaming dataset
language = "en"
buffer_size = 100
streaming_dataset = load_dataset("mozilla-foundation/common_voice_17_0", language, split="train",
                                 use_auth_token=True, trust_remote_code=True, streaming=True)

dataset = streaming_dataset.shuffle(seed=1137, buffer_size=buffer_size)

# Buffer and select a sample
common_voice = [sample for _, sample in zip(range(buffer_size), dataset)]
sample = random.choice(common_voice)

# Get the file URL and download it
audio_file_url = sample["audio"]["url"]

local_audio_path = "temp_audio_file.mp3"  # Define the local path
with requests.get(audio_file_url, stream=True) as r:
    r.raise_for_status()
    with open(local_audio_path, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=8192):
            f.write(chunk)

# Load the audio file locally
waveform, sample_rate = torchaudio.load(local_audio_path)

# Clean up the local file after use
os.remove(local_audio_path)


The url is not provided in the dictionary called 'sample', just the path where it would download the audio file if it wasn't a streaming dataset. Is there some way to get the download url from this or using a different method?
